# How to set focus of a dialog window?

Tags: front-end, gui-construction

I have a dialog, which, when pops up, requests input from the user. How can I set the window up that the focus is on the `InputField` of the new window (i.e. the caret stands in the `InputField`), so that when the user starts typing, it is immediately registered by the field? At the moment, I have to click inside the field first to make it the active control on screen.

```
DialogInput[{InputField["", String], Button["Ok", DialogReturn[]]}]
```

Comment: I look forward to seeing the answer to this one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After István Zachar's points, I was investigating `Input` definitions to learn more. It seams that 2 years later WRI changed approach from `SelectionMove` based to more automatic `BoxReferenceFind`.

#### usage

So what we only have to do is to set `BoxID` option for fields of interest and find those references when we want, with:

```
MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
 FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind[ 
   FE`BoxReference[
     _NotebookObject, {{ID_String}}, 
     FE`BoxOffset -> {FE`BoxChild[1]},   
     FE`SearchStart -> "StartFromBeginning"
   ]
 ]
]
```

This is a way more flexible approach, e.g. you can easily put `InputField` somewhere else and you don't have to change `SelectionMove` steps to get there.

#### example

```
DynamicModule[{name = "", surname = "", setFocus}
  , Column[{
        InputField[Dynamic@name, String, BoxID -> "name"]
      , InputField[Dynamic@surname, String, BoxID -> "surname"]
      , Button["setFocusToFirst", setFocus[EvaluationNotebook[], "name"]]
    }]
  , SynchronousInitialization -> False
  , Initialization :> (
        setFocus[nb_, ID_] :=  MathLink`CallFrontEnd[
            FrontEnd`BoxReferenceFind[ FE`BoxReference[
                nb
              , {{ID}}
              , FE`BoxOffset -> {FE`BoxChild[1]}
              , FE`SearchStart -> "StartFromBeginning"
            ]]
        ]
      ; setFocus[EvaluationNotebook[], "surname"]
    )
]
```

Comment: It is great that this can be done.  It is a travesty that users have to poke around in the internals of Mathematica to accomplish a simple task like this.

Comment: Now it's only missing the tab key jump order control !

Comment: @P.Fonseca On Windows it switches InputFields with Tab quite well.

Comment: Right. But through which order? Can you change the default order? In most visual languages, you can easily change the order of these jumps...

Comment: @P.Fonseca what do you mean by order in case of nonregular layout full of InputFields? You want to be able to provide list of tags (here BoxID) to go through when pressing Tab?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, most languages just use a kind of sequence ID parameter (it just searches for the next element, following a canonical order of the ID parameter or of an orderID parameter). This allows for old methods: name the objects 10, 20, 30, etc, so that you still have room in between, just in case something is missing during design phase. Having a list of BoxID also seems a good possibility (more clean; although I'm not sure if easier or more complex when working with dynamically generated interfaces; I have a lot of them... kind of objects that the user adds in between others...)

Comment: @P.Fonseca I see, going through explicit list should be doable with `EventHandler`, don't know if BoxRefferenceFind can handle patterns or find all indexed Boxes in given Cell for more automatic approach.

Comment: I think this deserves to be the definitive answer. Thanks for the research!

Comment: @IstvánZachar Thanks for the accept :)

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for figuring this out; it's helped a lot.  But I've noticed a bug in the first method (at least in version `11.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 18, 2017)`) -- editing the cell in which the GUI has been evaluated (e.g., delete the trailing `]`) shifts the focus to the *originally* focused inputfield, and any attempt to move the cursor is unsuccessful -- the notebook becomes unusable.  This is not an issue with the second method.

Comment: @Kuba (continued) Could the problem be that `setFocus` appears in the argument of `Composition` outside of the `DynamicModule`?

Comment: @jjc385 It really breaks, it seems that `CellDynamicExpression` wasn't fully fixed: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/126655/5478. I will delete this example as this is a long term problem and I don't believe it will be fixed anytime soon. Thanks for a feedback.

Answer (score 14):

Since `Input` is a `DialogInput`, it seemed reasonable to peek into `Input`'s structure to understand how the focus is set. After removing the `ReadProtected` attribute I've realized that there is no neat way to do it, as WRI itself has done the reposition of the focus via successive `SelectionMove` calls.

This example below is not the original but a modified version, as the original `Input` definition only includes one `InputField` but no other expressions (like a `Button`). Note that it is not documented that you can use `Initialization` in dialogs, moreover it is colored red by the syntax highlighter to suggest an invalid option.

```
DialogInput[{InputField["", String], Button["Ok", DialogReturn[]]},
 Initialization :> (FrontEndExecute[{
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[#1, Before, Notebook, 
       AutoScroll -> False],
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[#1, Next, Cell, 2, AutoScroll -> False],
      FrontEnd`SelectionMove[#1, Previous, CellContents, 
       AutoScroll -> False],
      FrontEnd`FrontEndToken[#1, "MovePreviousPlaceHolder"]
      }] &), ShowCellBracket -> True, Selectable -> True]
```

Comment: +1. I used similar code for my syntax highlighter generator, but wasn't succesful in trying to adopt it here. Good that you managed - another good example of how this is done.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Leonid and Istvan, you all may be interested in fact that WRI changed approach and use now ``FrontEnd`ReferenceBoxFind`` which is quite handy and more general.

Comment: @Kuba This seems interesting, but do you possess **any** further information about where, how, and who uses `ReferenceBox*` and `BoxReference*` functions? It is hard to experiment with them without any pointer on what they do.

Comment: Only from my own tests, and not much. E.g you can put `BoxID` almost everythere and it can be simple string.

Answer (score 4):

What's wrong with `Input[""]`?

Comment: I must assume it is not general enough, that he is building an entire dialog and that example given is quite reduced.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with `Input` but as Spartacus has pointed out, it is not general enough. Nevertheless, this pointed me to the right direction, so thanks David!

Comment: Spartacus is right. My suggestion was really aimed at quick fix. By the way, István, how did you manage to peek into `Input`'s structure?

Comment: @David: The usual way: by removing all attributes (`Attributes[Input] = {}`) and then querying the definition as `??Input`. This trick could give useful insight only if the symbol is `ReadProtected` (meaning that most of its definition is written in _Mathematica_ instead of C or whatnot), or not even then.