# How can I draw a variable number of dynamic, interactive objects, preserving their internal states?

Tags: graphics, dynamic, eventhandler

Consider the following toy example:

I have a "dynamical, interactive" graphics primitive like the following:

```
ClearAll[dynamicPoint];
dynamicPoint[point_List] := DynamicModule[{color = Red},
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@{PointSize@0.1, color, Point@point},
   {"MouseClicked" :> (
      If[color === Red,
       color = Green, color = Red
       ]
      )}
   ]
  ]
```

If I use the above function instead of the regular primitive `Point`, I get a point that changes color when I click on it:

[image]

This is all well and fine, but now I want to be able to add more dynamical points like this by clicking on the graphics.
The naive way would be to wrap the whole `Graphics` into another `EventHandler` with an appropriately set event, like in the following:

```
DynamicModule[{
  allData = <|"NumberOfPoints" -> 1, 
    "PointsCoordinates" -> {{-1, 0}}|>
  },
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{
    Dynamic@Table[
      dynamicPoint[allData["PointsCoordinates"][[pointIndex]]],
      {pointIndex, Range@allData["NumberOfPoints"]}
      ]
    },
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
   ],
  {"MouseClicked" :> (
     allData["NumberOfPoints"]++;
     AppendTo[allData["PointsCoordinates"], MousePosition["Graphics"]]
     )},
  PassEventsDown -> True
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see, I can now add points, but I lost all the ability to change their colors.
As I understand it, this happens because when I click on an existing point the corresponding change-color event is triggered (it's easy to check), but immediately after the `EventHandler` associated with the whole `Graphics` is also triggered, causing a redraw of all the points, and therefore of all the `DynamicModule`s associated with them, in which the local variables are initialized again.

I think the most obvious way to avoid this problem is to prevent the outer `EventHandler` to be triggered when I click on a point, but how can I accomplish that?

I *can* put a check inside the outer event handler to make it redraw only when the mouse click is not on an already occupied part of the graphics, but I don't want to do it in this way because that would require me to change the code in this check every time I change the actual things produced by `dynamicPoint`.
In my actual project I want these objects to be also dynamically resizable, which would make this solution hardly feasible.

Another method I thought was to add an element to `allData` marking whether the mouse is on a point or not.
I could easily set this flag to `True` with a `MouseMoved` event in the `EventHandler` of every point, and then checks whether the flag is true when the outer `EventHandler` is triggered.
The problem with this is that I cannot think of an easy way to set this flag back to `False` when the mouse exits the point, as there seems to be no `MouseExited` event.

### EDIT:

As of Kuba's suggestion, to have the two `EventHandler` events not interfere with each other it is enough to add the option `PassEventUp -> False` to the inner `EventHandler`s.
Using this we get the following:

```
ClearAll[dynamicPoint];
dynamicPoint[point_List] := DynamicModule[{color = Red},
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@{PointSize@0.1, color, Point@point},
   {"MouseClicked" :> (
      If[color === Red,
       color = Green, color = Red
       ]
      )},
   PassEventsUp -> False
   ]
  ]

DynamicModule[{
  allData = <|"NumberOfPoints" -> 1,
    "PointsCoordinates" -> {{-1, 0}}|>
  },
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{
    Dynamic@Table[
      dynamicPoint[allData["PointsCoordinates"][[pointIndex]]],
      {pointIndex, Range@allData["NumberOfPoints"]}
      ]
    },
   Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}
   ],
  {"MouseClicked" :> (
     allData["NumberOfPoints"]++;
     AppendTo[allData["PointsCoordinates"], MousePosition["Graphics"]]
     )},
  PassEventsDown -> True
  ]
 ]
```

[image]

As you can see, we still have the problem that redrawing all the points when a new one is added, all the `DynamicModule`s reinitialize their variables and so all the objects' states reinitialize.

How can we solve this?

Comment: Actually I just realized that `PassEventsUp -> False` put into the inner `EventHandler`s solved the problem, great! Did you mean this with your comment? Because with `PassEventDown -> False` put into the outer event handler it seems I just prevent the inner ones (of the points) to be triggered, and if I put `PassEventDown -> False` into the inner event handlers it doesn't do anything

Comment: @Kuba there is still a problem though: when the points are redrawn (clicking somewhere else in the graphics), their internal states are initialized again. Meaning with this that when I add a new point all the previous points go back to their initial states. How do you solve that?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of the problem. Not sure how to solve it without having external (graphics level) list of coordinates and colors which would govern than.

Comment: Would you kindly include complete code for the last almost-working example?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard done, see the edit

Comment: I'd say closely related: [Is there a better way to repeatedly add elements to a Graphics(Box)?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46746/5478). Shortly, there isn't any general way to add objects to the scene without preparing the scene (Graphics) for this during creation.

Comment: In version 10.1.0 under Windows the code you added does not produce the behavior shown.  I am not able to turn any of the dots green; I can only add new red dots. ***EDIT***, no, something in my default configuration is causing this; a -noinit start makes it work as shown.  Very odd.  Now I have to try to track that down.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps I am missing some subtlety in your problem description, but it seems to me you are trying make things more complicated than necessary. I don't see why you don't alter the state of your interactive graphics objects directly using just one `EventHandler` For your example, such an approach takes the following form.

```
With[{size = .03},
  DynamicModule[{pts = {}},
    EventHandler[
      Dynamic[
        Graphics[If[Length[pts] < 1, {}, pts],
          PlotRange -> 10,
          Frame -> True]],
      {"MouseClicked" :>
         Module[
             {xy = MousePosition["Graphics"],
              cntrs = pts[[All, 3, 1]],
              pxy, pclicked},
           If[Length[pts] < 1 || Length[pxy = Nearest[cntrs, xy, {1, .4}]] == 0, 
             AppendTo[pts, {Red, PointSize[size], Point[xy]}],
             {pindex} = Pick[Range @ Length @ pts, cntrs, pxy[[1]]];
             pts[[pindex, 1]] = If[pts[[pindex, 1]] === Red, Green, Red]]]}]]]
```

[image: panel]

This produces a graphics panel where clicking at a position that is not too close to an already existing point produces a new red point. Clicking on an existing point flips its color.

Comment: The reason is modularity. If I do it this way every other interactive element of the point I want to implement will have to be added to the checks in the outer event handler. Also the size itself of the points may not be fixed (and they may not be points). I want to be able to add features to the points without having to modify the code with which their are included into the graphics

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you.  Store the clicked color values by coordinate outside of `dynamicPoint`.

```
ClearAll[dynamicPoint];

color[_] := Red;

dynamicPoint[point_List] := With[{col := color[point]},
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@{PointSize@0.1, col, 
     Point@point}, {"MouseClicked" :> (If[col === Red, col = Green, col = Red])}, 
   PassEventsUp -> False]]

DynamicModule[{allData = <|"NumberOfPoints" -> 1, 
    "PointsCoordinates" -> {{-1, 0}}|>}, 
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Dynamic@
     Table[dynamicPoint[allData["PointsCoordinates"][[pointIndex]]], {pointIndex, 
       Range@allData["NumberOfPoints"]}]}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {"MouseClicked" :> (allData["NumberOfPoints"]++;
     AppendTo[allData["PointsCoordinates"], MousePosition["Graphics"]])}, 
  PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

Of course that could be written other ways as well e.g. making `color` local to the main `DynamicModule` expression.

```
ClearAll[dynamicPoint];

dynamicPoint[color_][point_List] := With[{col := color[point]},
  EventHandler[
   Dynamic@{PointSize@0.1, col, 
     Point@point}, {"MouseClicked" :> (If[col === Red, col = Green, col = Red])}, 
   PassEventsUp -> False]]

DynamicModule[{allData = <|"NumberOfPoints" -> 1, "PointsCoordinates" -> {{-1, 0}}|>,
   color}, color[_] := Red;
 EventHandler[
  Graphics[{Dynamic@
     Table[dynamicPoint[color][
       allData["PointsCoordinates"][[pointIndex]]], {pointIndex, 
       Range@allData["NumberOfPoints"]}]}, Frame -> True, 
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}], {"MouseClicked" :> (allData["NumberOfPoints"]++;
     AppendTo[allData["PointsCoordinates"], MousePosition["Graphics"]])}, 
  PassEventsDown -> True]]
```

(Sorry for the hideous code formatting but I don't want to bother to manually format it unless I know this is going in the right direction.)

Comment: I like the approach, makes it very easy to handle the expressions. I found another solution myself storing instead the colors as a list of held variables stored into `allData`, which work but makes it tricky to handle them afterwards (hence my other question on setting held variables). To you think there is any inherent advantage in using one approach instead of the other (except for the semantic used to handle the variables)?

Comment: well I'm sure you can see the link between this question and [my other one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138397/27539), which raises the following issue: with your present solution all points will be redrawn when changing the color of a single one. To prevent this we should use method of held variables, which however incurs in the problem I raised in my other question: how to make sure the variables are still defined in the FE. How do we come out of this? :)

Comment: @glS If we get the other question answered to your satisfaction I shall try to apply it here.