# Dynamic Symbol tracking from a list of Symbols

Tags: dynamic

A minimal example for the **Bonus** in [Can a Dynamic be attached to the single elements of a list?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/138397/121)

```
DynamicModule[{foo = Hold[$1, $2], $1 = 0, $2 = 0},
  {
    Dynamic[Print["redrawing first"]; foo[[1]]],
    Dynamic[Print["redrawing second"]; foo[[2]]],
    Button["first", ++$1],
    Button["second", ++$2]
  }
]
```

Observe the **Messages** window as these buttons are pressed.  The *redraw* messages are printed independently after the initial evaluation, i.e. you can get a message list like:

> redrawing first
>
> redrawing second
>
> redrawing first
>
> redrawing first
>
> redrawing first
>
> redrawing first
>
> redrawing second

(corresponding to 4, 1, in the expression)

By what mechanism does *Mathematica* track the value of `$1` or `$2` changing and update each Dynamic individually despite neither Symbol appearing explicitly in the bodies?

Comment: I imagine this behavior has come up before.  If anyone can suggest a duplicate please either comment here or if you have sufficient *reputation* vote to close as a duplicate if appropriate.

Comment: The following might be an explanation. The symbols that are tagged for updating are all symbols that are used for the evaluation of the contents. At the first display of the DM, the kernel has to evaluate foo[[1]]. That requires `$1` and therefore `$1` is tagged with the dynamic object number for foo[[1]]. That is confirmed by the result of Internal`GetTrackedIDs[]. Therefore, each time when we press the button for $1, also the output of foo[[1]] is updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From:

**[tutorial / AdvancedDynamicFunctionality / Automatic Updates of Dynamic Objects](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedDynamicFunctionality.html#440620996)**

> [...] If a variable value, or some other state of the system, changes, the dynamic output should be updated immediately. [...] It is critical that dependencies be tracked so that dynamic outputs are evaluated only when necessary.

And the most important part:

> [...] the system keeps track of which variables or other trackable entities are actually encountered during the process of evaluating a given expression. Data is then associated with those variable(s) identifying which dynamic expressions need to be notified if the given variable receives a new value. [...]

And how this association/building dependency tree is performed can be adjusted by `TrackedSymbols` option. By default it is `All` so it will be scanning and gathering symbols needed when `foo[[1]]` is evaluated.

For `TrackedSymbols -> Full` it will stop on a visible level, so only changes to `foo` itself will trigger changes.

Comment: I am sure I have read and forgotten that.  Hopefully gIS is as satisfied by this answer as I am.

Comment: At the moment do you know what *other trackable entities* means?  I thought only Symbols could be tracked.  I really need to read this tutorial again.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard don't know much but it seems that `CurrentValue[$FrontEnd, {TaggingRules, "key"}]` can be automatically sensitive for specific "key" not to `CurrentValue` or `TaggingRules` in general. It probably refers to things like `Mouseover` and other event related entities too.,

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and Kuba: what I don't fully understand if how this tracking process happens. I get now that it happens during evaluation, which explains how the `Dynamic` can find out at all about `$1` and `$2`. But given that `$1` in this example starts with a value, the evaluation sequence of `foo[[1]]` should end up directly into the numerical value `0`. So does this mean that the evaluation sequence of an expression wrapped in `Dynamic` is a special one, in the sense that *at every single evaluation step* the result is checked for trackable symbols?

Comment: so what happens if `foo[[1]] = $1` and `$1 = $2` and `$2 = 3`? which symbols end up being tracked? EDIT: well I just tried and indeed changing the value of both `$1` and `$3` triggers correctly the first dynamic, using the code: `DynamicModule[{foo = Hold[$1, $2], $1 = Hold[$3], $2 = 0, $3 = 0},
 {
  Dynamic[Print["redrawing first"]; ReleaseHold@foo[[1]]],
  Dynamic[Print["redrawing second"]; foo[[2]]],
  Button["first", ++$1],
  Button["second", ++$2],
  Button["third", ++$3]
  }
 ]`. I guess this confirms what I was saying above?

Comment: @glS Kuba should answer too but I believe all the symbols would be tracked; I think it is considering `Trace[ foo[[1]] ]` and making a list of Symbols that are used.

Comment: Don't have much time now, will try to add some examples later but if you run: `foo[[1]] = $1 and $1 = $2 and $2 = 3` then Kernel says, 'foo changed, update DynamicBoxObject[id]', but kernel will also rewrite dependency tree and this dynamic will be only related to `foo` and `$2` alone, as you replaced `$1` inside with its value.

Comment: Shortly, for default case, for `Dynamic[foo[[1]] ]` - create DynamicObject[id], take recursively FullDefinitions of all symbols starting from `foo` (going through `$1` `$2`), associate those symbols with DynamicObject[id] so that whenever they change you will send a message to the FrontEnd about updating.