# Is it Ok/meaningful to have assignment in Refresh, e.g. Refresh[y=x…]?

Tags: dynamic

Could someone please explain the following behaviors?

I don't know if it's related to `TrackedSymbols`, assignment, evaluation of rhs of assignment, or initialization in `DynamicModule`.

```
DynamicModule[{x, y},
 Column[{
   Slider[Dynamic[x]],
   Dynamic[Refresh[y = x, TrackedSymbols -> {y}]],
   Dynamic[y]
   }]]
```

Without the initilization of `x` and `y`, only the 2nd `Dynamic` updates.

And, if `y=x` is changed to `y=x+1`, neither `Dynamic` updates;

`y=x++`, or `RandomReal[]`, which of course makes `Slider` pointless, both `Dynamic` update.

Now if I change the initilization part to e.g. `x=0,y=0`,

then in the case of `y=x, y=x+1, y=x++`, neither `Dynamic` updates;

only those with `y=RandomReal[]` updates.

I don't know if the above is useful in real life. I just create them to understand better the behavior `Refresh` wrapped in `Dynamic` and if it's OK/meaningful to use assignment in `Refresh`.

Thanks a lot.

=================================

I put my newest questions here for better readability.

I'd like ask regarding #4 of the generic situation.

Q1: Is my understanding correct? when `Dynamic@Refresh` runs for the 1st time, y's state is changed from no_initial value to y=0, which is passed by x via assignment.

Q1-1: And when y is provided an initial value of 0, in the case of y=x++, y's state doesn't change, when `Dynamic@Refresh` runs for the 1st time, and therefore, it doesn't run into `Infinity`, unless use `++x`, as you suggested.

Q2: When I drag the slider thumb, why the newest value of x can't be passed to y via assignment? Is it because I set explicit trackedsymbol to {y}. This part is still quite confusing for me. (The situation with x++ or RandomReal[] isn't the same as y=x+1, since neither of them is related to slider).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### generic situation

So what happens when you run the code from above:

1. during evaluation nothing special because `Dynamic` holds it's arguments till it is displayed
2. during typesetting all those gui elements are converted to appropriate boxes, rendered and the FrontEnd starts to care about updating DynamicBox or handle SliderBox
3. there is no guarantee that `Slider` will give `x` it's initial `0` before the subsequent `Dynamics` are rendered. It will be the rat race but here nothing fancy happens.

   so Slider gives `x` a value `0`
4. `Dynamic[Refresh[..` is displayed for the first time and `y=x` is run. It changes `y` state so it makes parent `Dynamic` being refreshed. Next time `x` is the same so it stays as it was.
5. `Dynamic[y]` is displayed showing `0` as expected
6. From now on nothing fancy should happen. `Slider` changes `x` and none of `Dynamics` below should be updated. The first one has an explicit list of tracked symbols while the second is only `y` dependent.

You can read more how dependency tree is build in:

https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138455/5478

Now let's talk about your doubts.

#### specific cases

- > Without the initilization of `x` and `y`, only the 2nd Dynamic updates.

  This should not happen and I'd call it a bug, neither of them should be triggered according to what I said above.

  Strange things with crude `Dynamic[var]` happen more often, read more in:

  [What is the difference between Dynamic[x] and Dynamic[ h[x] ] for DynamicModule variables?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/100828/5478)

  You can confirm that simple change to `Dynamic[{y}]` makes it behave as expected.
- > And, if y=x is changed to y=x+1, neither Dynamic updates;

  Correct and expected (see 7). But notice what happens at the beginning:

  ```
    Refresh[Print[RandomReal[]]; y = x + 1, TrackedSymbols -> {y}]
  ```

  This shows the `Print` is called 2-3 times, it is because `Slider` gives `x` initial value `0` then when the second dynamic is displayed `y` gets `x+1` which  triggers this dynamic again because `y` was changed. `x` hasn't changed though so next time `y` will get the same value, `1`, and won't be triggered.

  And the `Slider` does not matter. **Only the very first rendering made that happen**.
- > y=x++, or RandomReal[], which of course makes Slider pointless,  both Dynamic update

  Unlike the previous case, now `x++` changes each time and so does `y` and so `Refresh` is triggered and `x++` again and so on.

  Related topic:

  [Problem with UpdateInterval](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9766/problem-with-updateinterval)
- > Now if I change the initilization part to e.g. x=0,y=0, then in the case of y=x, y=x+1, y=x++, neither Dynamic updates;

  `y=x, y=x+1` are easy and explained before. The last one is interesting, why doesn't it run into `Infinity`? Because `x++` returns previous value of `x` which was `0`, the same as `y's` so the outer dynamic wasn't triggered and it won't anymore due to `TrackedSymbols`.

  But change `x++` to `++x` :) this returns new value of `x` so the loop begins.
- > only those with y=RandomReal[] updates.

  again, assignment to `y`, each time different value makes it being triggered and so on.
- > I don't know if the above is useful in real life. I just create them to understand better the behavior Refresh wrapped in Dynamic and if it's OK/meaningful to use assignment in Refresh.

  Here is a whole topic about usefulness or not of `Refresh`:

  [What is the point of Refresh if Dynamic has an UpdateInterval option?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/14368/5478)

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and detailed answer. I'd like to ask about generic situation #4. Q1: you mean, the state of y is changed from no_initial value to y=0, which passed by x via assignment? Q2: why when I drag slider to change the value of x, but its newest value can't be passed to y? Only because the trackedsyombol is explicitly set to {y}, and therefore, doesn't work? Thanks again.

Comment: @Yaofeng yes, from 'no value' to `0` and yes all those updates are triggered by the `Dynamic[Refresh[..`, slider here should have no influence.

Comment: sorry, I'm still confused. When slider is dragged, x's value is updated in the kernel, and this newest value won't be passed to y via assignment `(y=x)`? If not so, how come `x++` works, which, I think, is also passing x's value to y ? Thanks again.

Comment: `y = x++` is run from `Dynami[Refresh[`, it changes `y` value so `Refresh` is triggered again. When `x` is changed via Slider then only `x` is changed.  `y=x` does not care. Don't be sorry, I'm not the best in explaining stuff :)

Comment: this means: 1. `x++` works because the change of x value occurs within `Dynamic[Refresh[`; it has nothing to do with `Slider`. 2. There isn't any communication between `Slider[Dynamic[` and `Dynamic[Refresh[`, even though both contain `x` ? If so, is this due to the HoldFirst attribute of Dynamic or some other reason ?

Comment: It seems I have another question. I put the code appearing in the post here. `DynamicModule[{x = 0, y = 0}, 
 Dynamic[Refresh[y = ++x, TrackedSymbols -> {y}]]]`, where y updates to `Infinity`. I found if the rule is changed to a delayed rule `:>`, y stops at 1. Could you please have a look ?

Comment: @Yaofeng about the last comment, I don't know why and how to judge it, FE often decides how to handle some cases on heuristics that are not documented, in order to make things more efficient etc. Notice that `TrackedSymbols` should always be used with `:>`, otherwise it will get evaluated. In you case it didn't matter because they are in `Refresh`, which is the first argument in `Dynamic`, which is held. Should have write more about that.