# Cursor Automatically Placed in InputField

Tags: inputfield, input-forms

When creating a DialogInput box with an input field, I'd like the created box to have the cursor already active in that box. That way one only has to type the input, not 1) click in the box then 2) type.

A simple example:

```
DialogInput[Column[{InputField[]}]]
```

creates a simple box that one has to click in first before entering any input.

How can I make the cursor automatically active in this box?

Comment: what you want is called to "set the focus", if you search for that you'll find a possible duplicate: [http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1454]?

Comment: @AlbertRetey Got it. You might fix the link above to remove the " ] " at the end.