# Giving the input focus to a particular input field

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, inputfield, user-interface

A couple of versions of Mathematica ago there was discussion of how one can set focus on a particular input field:

[How to set focus of a dialog window?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1454/how-to-set-focus-of-a-dialog-window)

http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/489107

Are any additional methods of accomplishing this possible in more recent versions of Mathematica?

Answer (score 3):

So to complement Kuba's answer, digging in the CloudObject source code (because there's that auth dialog) you find that even they still use the `BoxID` system. Look at:

```
FileNameJoin@{
  PacletFind["CloudObject"][[1]]["Location"],
  "Kernel",
  "Dialogs.m"
  }
```

where you'll find:

```
inptFld[dyn:Dynamic[expr_], boxid_, fldtype_, opts:OptionsPattern[]] := InputField[Dynamic[expr], fldtype, 
    ContinuousAction -> True,  
    System`BoxID -> boxid, 
    ImageSize -> {Full, Automatic},
    BaseStyle -> {
        FontFamily -> $BaseFontFamily,
  FontWeight -> "Regular",
  FontColor -> $InputTextColor,
        FontSize -> $InputFieldFontSize 
    },
    opts];
```

But apparently there is now this:

`` FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField ``

to be used like:

```
CreateDialog[
 inptFld[Dynamic[a], "asd", String],
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> (
   Refresh[
    FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], "asd"], None]
   )
 ]
```

Comment: Pity this does not work: ``CreateDialog[DynamicName[InputField[Dynamic[a], String], "asd"], 
 NotebookDynamicExpression :> (Refresh[
    FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], "asd"], 
    None])]``