# Problem with DialogInput and store variable

Tags: list-manipulation, dynamic, gui-construction, inputfield, dialog-window

Writing:

```
fct[input_, output_, type_] := Module[{}, DialogInput[DialogNotebook[
                                         {TextCell[input],
                                          InputField[Dynamic[output], type],
                                          DefaultButton[DialogReturn[output]]},
                                         Background -> Green,
                                         Magnification -> 1.5]]
                                     ];

list = ConstantArray[0, 10];

For[i = 1, i <= 10, i++,

    Clear[msg]; fct["Insert number:", msg, Number];

    list = ReplacePart[list, i -> msg]

   ]
```

through a mask it is possible to populate `list`.

However, if the first request is entered `1`, at the second request I would not like the box to be empty, but contain `1`, which can only be changed if desired.

Is it possible to do this by maintaining the structure proposed above?

Thank you!

Comment: What if the first is 2? Should the second be empty? Or should it always be initialized to the previous value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I'd do it:

```
fct[input_, init_, type_: Number] := DialogInput[
  {var = init}
, Pane[
    Column[
      { TextCell[input]
      , InputField[Dynamic[var], type, System`BoxID -> "number"]
      , DefaultButton[DialogReturn[var]]
      }
    ]
  , ImageMargins -> 5
  ]
, Background -> Green
, Magnification -> 1.5
, NotebookDynamicExpression :> (Refresh[
    FrontEnd`MoveCursorToInputField[EvaluationNotebook[], "number"]
  , None
  ])
];
```

and now just:

```
list = Rest@NestList[
  fct["Insert number:", #] &, 0, 10
]
```

More about `MoveCursorToInputField` in [152536](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152536/5478) and [1454](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1454/5478) but it is not relevant here.

Comment: @TeM yes, you can do it your way but since you are replacing parts of `list` later anyway I just skipped this part and you generate `list` directly.